# "Please set registry key HKLM..."

Tags: windows, .net-framework

When I try to run my application, an error message says:

> Please set registry key HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\InstallRoot to point to the .net framework install location

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more information: What application? Which version of .NET? Which version of Windows? Have you tried reinstalling the .NET Framework? Have you tried reinstalling the application?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some sort of corruption in your .NET Framework.
Microsoft has a tool to repair .NET framework.
Download link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/repair

If this does not resolve the problem then you could also try to run the .NET Framework 4.8 installer and reinstalling .NET Framework 3.5 by turning the Windows feature off and on.

**Running the .NET Framework 4.8 installer**

- Download the installer https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-web-installer
- Run the installer
- Reboot the system

**Reinstalling .NET Framework 3.5**

- Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off
- Uncheck ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" and press OK
- Reboot the computer
- Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off
- Check ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" and press OK
- Reboot the computer